# How do I use splice to remove the last character of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

say for example I have the word dictionary,
how do I code so that it produces

```
dictionar
dictiona
diction
dictio
dicti
dict
dic
di
d
```

(every last character is removed)

I currently have:

```
def generate_letter_removed(word):
    return_list4 = []
    for i in range(1, len(word)):
        q = word[:-1]
        return_list4.append(q)
    return return_list4

letter_removed = generate_letter_removed(word)
print(letter_removed)
```

but this produces "dictionar"

Answer (score 1):

Use string slicing:

```
word = "dictionary"
for i in range(len(word), 0, -1):
    print(word[:i])
```

Output:

```
dictionary
dictionar
dictiona
diction
dictio
dicti
dict
dic
di
d
```

As a function:

```
def slice_output(w):
    print('\n'.join(w[:i] for i in range(len(w), 0, -1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected your code

```
def generate_letter_removed(word):
    return_list4 = [word]
    for i in range(1, len(word)):
        q = word[:-i]
        return_list4.append(q)
    return return_list4
word=input("Enter A Word: ")
letter_removed = generate_letter_removed(word)
print(letter_removed)
```

> Output

```
Enter A Word: Dictionary
['Dictionary', 'Dictionar', 'Dictiona', 'Diction', 'Dictio', 'Dicti', 'Dict', 'Dic', 'Di', 'D']
```